# Arabic application using Flex Builder 4.5

Tags: android, apache-flex, ios, mobile, air

I am going to make an Arabic application using Flex builder 4.5. I have two questions that need to be answered

1. What is the difference between ActionScript Mobile Project and Flex Mobile Project. (AS Mobile Project supports iOS and Android but I doubt about it!!)
2. Is Arabic support available in Flex Mobile Projects or AS Mobile Projects? I know TLF supports Desktop and web apps but does it support mobile platforms?

cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> What is the difference between ActionScript Mobile Project and Flex
> ```
>
> Mobile Project. (AS Mobile Project
>   supports iOS and Android but I doubt
>   about it!!)

An ActionScript Mobile Project supports Android, iOS and Blackberry Playbook development; but has no support for the Flex Framework.  It is, basically, starting a project with a clean slate.  If you're a Flex Developer, building Flash Platform Apps w/o the Flex Framework is very different.

A Flex Mobile Project only supports Android development.  It gives you full access to the Flex Mobile Components.  An update that will add iOS and Blackberry Playbook support is expected this month (June 2011)

> ```
> Is Arabic support available in Flex Mobile Projects or AS Mobile
> ```
>
> Projects? I know TLF supports Desktop
>   and web apps but does it support
>   mobile platforms?

TLF is not recommended on mobile platforms.  I believe this is due to performance reasons.  Here is a good article about [localization in Flex](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_localization_pt1.html); unfortunately it does not address the mobile usage question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am quite new in flash/flex platform. I have much experience in iOS development. I need to target all mobile devices by using Adobe Air. Do you think should I start with flash or flex? Any suggestion?

Comment: @imran it depends what you want to do. You'll get better performance w/ a straight ActionScript project that does not use the Flex Framework.  But, if you're building a business application and need a lot of the UI Components (such as Drop Down Boxes, Lists, Buttons) or a layout/skinning framework then Flex is the way to go. If you're not building an app where this prebuilt component library will be beneficial; then go w/ AS3 only.

Comment: hmm I think I need to go with Flex. Is there any way to make mobile apps in Arabic by using adobe air?

Comment: I assume so; I thought the big thing w/ TLF in terms of internationalization was it supported right to left languages.  Is Arabic one of those?  Here is another resource:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fcf.html

Comment: yeah TLF supports arabic but I am not sure about it supports for mobile devices